# how to create an elastic search index which emulates my mysql db

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am new to elasticsearch and i am having tough time switching from mysql to elasticsearch

my Mysql my tables looks like this

```
    table :  test_request 
    +---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
    | test_id | device_name | ip_address   | user_name | time_stamp | show_flag |
    +---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
    |   1     |     d1      |   0.0.0.0    |   admin   |            |     Y     |
    +---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+

     
    table:  test_results 
    +----+---------+-----+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
    | id | test_id | cli |          xml          |           json          |             another json         | show_flag |
    +----+---------+-----+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
    | 1  |   1     |  c1 |  some xml format data |  {"some":"json here"}   |   {"some":" another json here"}  |     Y     |
    +----+---------+-----+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
    | 2  |   1     |  c2 |  some xml format data |  {"some":"json here"}   |   {"some":" another json here"}  |     Y     |
    +----+---------+-----+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
    | 3  |   1     |  c2 |  some xml format data |  {"some":"json here"}   |   {"some":" another json here"}  |     Y     |
    +----+---------+-----+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

the `test_id` field in the `test_request` table and the `id` field in the `test_results` table are `auto increment`.
 The `json` and `another json` fields are of data type `JSON`.

I am trying to use `elasticsearch_dsl` to create index and its mappings. I am going through the [docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to figure out how to do achieve this but i couldn't figure out three things

1. how to get the test_id to `auto increment`
2. how to make a field of `JSON` data type
3. Best way to setup a relationship between both (i partially understood nested could help here) but looking for the correct way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto increment` id columns play following rules in the SQL tables:

1. they are unique identifiers of the row
2. they allow to link rows between tables

To achieve this in elasticsearch you don't need a `auto increment` field. You can add document to elasticsearch index, and elasticsearch will add a unique id to it.

For JSON fields use simply [object datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html).

There are few options to setup relation like SQL join:

1. You can put `test_results` as `nested` objects within `test_request` document
2. You can use [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) field to link `test_results` documents to `test_request` document within the same index
3. You can denormalize and store every `test_result` into single document together with its `test_request`. It is ok, that `test_request` will be stored many times. Elasticsearch is primarily for searching anyway.

Which version you choose is up to you. It depends, how are you going to use your data, what kind of queries are you going to do. Can you collect all `test_results` together with the `test_request` and store it with the single call, or do you need store the `test_request` and the successively add `test_results`?

Successively updating nested field would mean reindexing the whole document every time. `Join datatype` is expensive for querying.

Denormalization adds space usage, but if the number of `test_results` per request is not large, then it is maybe the best option.

Comment: it is possible for me to get all the test_results and add them to test_request in one shot.